# OData migration in ASP.net 5 from asp.net 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, odata

How to do old OData controller migration in ASP.net 5 and MVC6.
i have a controller derived from ODataController and want to convert that into ASP.net5 specific code. please help.

the structure of my controller is

```
   namespace Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ODataRoutePrefix("MyData")]
    public class MyController : ODataController
    {
        [ODataRoute]
        [EnableQuery]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            .....
            return this.Ok(EntityList);
        }


        [ODataRoute("D.GetMyUser(userId = {userId}, tenantId = {tenantId} , mode = {mode})")]
        [EnableQuery]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetMyUser([FromODataUri] string userId, [FromODataUri] string tenantId, [FromODataUri] string mode)
        {
            .........
            return this.Ok(MyEntityList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a link to the odata nuget package and version you intend to use?

Comment: Is "https://github.com/OData/WebApi/tree/vNext" what you are looking for?

Comment: yes, thats what i am looking for but its someones personal implementation of odata. i was expecting similar package from microsoft, do you have any idea how to proceed.